# Hook a javascript event to page load

Tags: javascript, master-pages, asp.net, onload-event

I have an aspx that has the following javascript function being ran during the onload event of the body.

```
<body onload="startClock();">
```

However, I'm setting the aspx up to use a master page, so the body tag doesn't exist in the aspx anymore. How do I go about registering the startClock function to run when the page is hit and still have it use a masterpage?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you don't want to explicitly assign window.onload or use a framework, consider:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function startClock(){
    //do onload work
}
if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load',startClock,false); //W3C
} else {
    window.attachEvent('onload',startClock); //IE
}
</script>
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: +1 - I was too lazy to type this answer, but this is the way I would suggest someone does it too, with the same assumptions you initially state.

Comment: Of course, I would abstract the details a wee bit - hopefully that is obvious to the OP...

Comment: I must be missing something real obvious here, but where does the 'if' block of code go? You can't just dump that in a <script> tag can you?

Comment: You can stick it all in a script tag. I updated my answer to reflect it. This will force the 'if' logic to execute as the script is parsed so the startClock event is ready onload.

Comment: Easy and slick way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: What if document.attachEvent is null?

Comment: Since non-MS browsers are pretty good about implementing W3C DOM Level 2 recommendations, the 'else' exists for IE only. As Jason mentioned, we could(should) abstract the details and while we're at it we could add caution(is this a browser that doesn't support either event reg. model, is this function already registered, etc). I opted for simplicity in my example. Worth a downvote? I dunno.

Comment: In Chrome, `document.addEventListener` didn't work, but `window.addEventListener` did.

Answer (score 2):

Insert this anywhere in the body of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    //do something here
}
</script>
```

Comment: The only problem with this one is if other code, also pulled into the composite page, does the same thing - last in wins. Redefining window.onload works, but care should be taken to make sure it hasn't already been defined!

Comment: I have seen code that tests to see if `window.onload` is defined, and if so, refers to it in a temp variable, then "calls" that variable from within the *new* `window.onload`.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way is using a javascript framework like jQuery.
In jQuery you could define the on-load function in the following way:

```
$(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Or, if you don't like the short `$();` style:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Agreed. I've actually started using jQuery a few months after posting this question (nearly a year ago now), and I love it.

Comment: Newer versions of jQuery require the $(document).ready(...) style.

Comment: No. In never versions the behaviour of `$()` changed, but `$(some_function)` did not change.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    startClock();
});
```

This will invoke the startClock function at page load.

Comment: Nice, just don't forget to add ");" after the "}"

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @JulienVan. Have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Page.ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScrip(this.GetType(), "startup", "startClock();", true);
```

or using prototype

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  // code here
});
```

Comment: I assume you mean RegisterClientScriptBlock?