# Run a Javascript On Page Load

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I would like to know how to run a javascript function on page load..  in my asp.net page. I do not want to do it in from my .cs file OnLoad, I want to keep it in the aspx page if at all possible.

I am new to javascript so any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hook a javascript event to page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946518/hook-a-javascript-event-to-page-load)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadJavaScript()
{
// add code here
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="loadJavaScript()">
<h1>Java script on load demo</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

There is a nice example [here](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/document/_BODY_onLoad.html)

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
            function() {
                //your code here
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an onload event to the body html element.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML body onload event.

or

Use a javascript framework like jQuery and use the $(document).ready() event. [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RegisterStartupScript` to register your javascript snippets from the code behind:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408.aspx