# I'm unable to get image in canvas in html5, what to do?

Tags: html, image, html5-canvas

I have checked this code from my w3schools where its working well.

But when I run this code in my browser, it's not working.

The image does not get displayed in the canvas. Also, I tried the same code in w3schools browser somewhere else, but still it's not working in that browser either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Image to use:</p>
        <img id="scream" src="flower.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277"><p>Canvas:</p>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">

        <script>
            var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
            var img=document.getElementById("scream");
            ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the basics? Like, is the image in the same folder as the .htm file..?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the image directly, instead of taking it out of the `<img>`-tag

```
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 10, 10);
};
imageObj.src = 'flower.jpg';
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that load of an image is asynchronous, so your Javascript code might run before the image finish his loading. Because of that when `ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10)` is called `img` have no complete data and draws nothing on canvas.

To solve that you need to wait the image to completely load. Javascript give you the ability to setup a function to run when an image  is completely loaded.

All code that depends of the image data should be put inside the `onload` callback.

```
img.onload = function(){ 
    ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
}
```

Your script with the modified parts:

```
<script>
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var img=document.getElementById("scream");
    img.onload = function(){ 
        ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
    }
</script>
```

If the `src` is correct doesn't matter if the image is loaded from a html tag or created dynamically in Javascript with `new Image()`, the `onload` method works for both.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run the javascript on load, rather than directly in body. Change you javascript into this and it should work (at least it does in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dessibelle/mPrBh/)):

```
function setup_canvas() {
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var img=document.getElementById("scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
}

window.onload = setup_canvas;
```

Also, as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946518/hook-a-javascript-event-to-page-load) explicitly setting `window.onload` is not a very good practice, as it might be overwritten by subsequent scripts, so for anything other than testing you would want to use a framework or `addEventListener`/`attachEvent`.