# Picture not drawn on "reload page"

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, reload

This code displays a picture in a Canvas:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"><title>canpic</title>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache"><META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<style>
  canvas { border: 42px solid green; }
</style>
</head><body>
CANVAS PICTURE TEST
<br>
<canvas id="pinaka" width="600" height="370">
No HTML5 in this browser!
</canvas>
<br>
<p id="message"></p>
<script>
var can; // Canvas
var ctx; // Canvas context
var backimage=new Image();
function test1() {
  can=document.getElementById("pinaka");
  ctx=can.getContext('2d');
  backimage.src="images/p1.jpg";
  alert('drawing');
  ctx.drawImage(backimage,0,0);
}
$(document).ready(function() { test1(); })
</script>
</body></html>
```

This works well on several browsers I tried, with one exception:

When I first load this page on Safari 4, the picture is drawn well, but when I do a page reload (Apple-R key), only the canvas border is drawn, but the interior of the canvas stays blank. There is also no error shown in the error console. I could verify that my function test1() has been called after the reload, because the alert box shows up.

Is this just a bug in Safari 4, which I have to accept, or is there a problem with my code? At least with two other browsers tried (Camino and SeaMonkey), the code works well.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16814721/2252829

Comment: @Gustavo Carvalho: This posting suggests to do the drawing in the onload function. I tried this, but the behaviour was even worse than in my original code, in that the picture is now *never* displayed, and not only with Safari, but with other browsers as well. I will put my changed version in the original posting, so you can see how I have done it.

Comment: @GustavoCarvalho: Sorry, my mistake. Indeed, it DOES work now with the solution you have pointed out! Thanks a lot.

Comment: BTW, what is the best way at Stackoverflow to mark a question as answered? I also would like to show my corrected code, but if I understand it correctly, this should not be done by editing my original posting.

Comment: You are welcome! You did right by answering yor own question.  Just remember to accept it later (I think there's a delay before you be able to do this). Anyway, you can also give an upvote to any other questions or answers on SÓ that are helpful. This way good posts get better visibility on SO and might help other people in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my function in th following way:

```
function test1() {
  can=document.getElementById("pinaka");
  ctx=can.getContext('2d');
  backimage.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(backimage,0,0);
  }
  backimage.src="images/p1.jpg"; // triggers loading the picture
```

}

Now it works (because it is ensured that the picture is loaded before drawing begins.