# Fix position change with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I am trying to achive a fixed position after a certain point of the page is passed using CSS    JS and HTML. 
Also I don't know the bet aproach in loading the function into the html doc, I was thinking on using the onload...

Here is what I have done until now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var left1 = document.getElementById("left1");
            var origOffsetY = left1.offsetTop;

            function onScroll(e) {
                window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? left1.style.position = "fixed":
                left1.style.position="absolute";
            }

            document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
        </script language="JavaScript">
        <style>
            #main {
                position: relative;
                width: 620px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                height: 1800px;
            }
            #left1{
                position: absolute;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                left: 0px;
                top: 10px;
                height: 200px;
                width: 300px;
                background-color: #F6D565;
            }
            #right1{
                position:absolute; 
                font-family: sans-serif;
                top: 10px;
                right: 0px;
                height: 300px;
                width: 300px;
                background-color: #DFFCC2;
            }
            #right2{
                position:absolute;  
                top: 320px;
                right: 0px;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                height:300px; 
                width: 300px;
                background-color: #DFFCC2;
            }
            #right3{
                position:absolute;
                top: 630px;
                right: 0px;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                height: 300px;
                width: 300px;
                background-color: #DFFCC2;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div id="main">
            <div id="left1">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
            <div id="right1">bbb</div>
            <div id="right2">cccccccccccccccccccccc</div>
            <div id="right3">ddd</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And the question is? Your code seems to work ok

Comment: I want the aaa... text to remain fixed on the screen when I scroll and also I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null

Comment: in the current state it scrolls with the page and I want it to remain fixed after a certain amount of px

Comment: That error comes because you call the var origOffsetY = left1.offsetTop; before element with id "left1" exists (/is added to the DOM)

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wigaca/1/edit)**

The DOM is not available when you are trying to access div with id left1.

So your first line `var left1 = document.getElementById("left1");` will give error.

Instead Wrap your current code within window.onload

```
<script>
       window.onload = function() {     
            var left1 = document.getElementById("left1");
            var origOffsetY = left1.offsetTop;

            function onScroll(e) {
               console.log("calling scroll")
                window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? left1.style.position = "fixed":
                left1.style.position="absolute";
            }

            document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
                                  }
  </script>
```

Else place your javascript just above the `</body>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to load your script after the DOM is created. The time you are trying to parse `var left1 =document.getElementById("left1");` DOM hasn't created yet so `var left1` is null

TRY:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
           //YOUR CSS
        </style>
    </head>
    <body >
        <div id="main">
            <div id="left1">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
            <div id="right1">bbb</div>
            <div id="right2">cccccccccccccccccccccc</div>
            <div id="right3">ddd</div>
        </div>
 <script>
            var left1 = document.getElementById("left1");
            var origOffsetY = left1.offsetTop;

            function onScroll(e) {
                window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? left1.style.position = "fixed":
                left1.style.position="absolute";
            }

            document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
        </script language="JavaScript">
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

By changing `position` you have to rearrange your item.

Try:

```
function onScroll(e) {
    if (window.scrollY >= origOffsetY) {
        left1.style.position = "fixed";
        left1.style.left = "66px"
    } else {
        left1.style.position = "absolute";
        left1.style.left = "0px";
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VCmZ6/1/)

Comment: yes but by using the example of "laaposto" a bug appears, the div is float to the left out of the "main" div, any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `onload` to call a function ***after*** the page is loaded like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onLoad(){
        var left1 = document.getElementById("left1");
        var origOffsetY = left1.offsetTop;
    }
    function onScroll(e) {
        window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? left1.style.position = "fixed":
        left1.style.position="absolute";
    }
    document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
</script>
```

and replace

```
<body>
```

with:

```
<body onload="onload()">
```

Note that you can still leave the script in the header of your page *(between `<head>` and `</head>`)*.

You can use `window.addEventListener()` if you don't like `<body onload="onload">`, but IE won't support this. See *["Hook a javascript event to page load"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/946676/1935077)* for details.