# Whats the best way to listen, using javascript or jQuery, for if a page is in the process of loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I could be missing something simple here, I want to add a waiting cursor to my admin when my page is "loading" for example, when I click a pagination link to go from page 2 to page 3, at the moment I'm using a css class "btn-wait"

```
$('.btn-wait').on('click', function() {
    $(document.body).css({"cursor", "wait"});
})
```

Is there a better way of doing this, something like

```
$(window).is('loading', function() ....
```

Obviously I cant use a .ready because I want to apply the waiting cursor when my page is loading, or is it best to keep using this class like I am doing?

Comment: Is the pagination results being returned by ajax or is it loading an entirely new page?

Comment: There's no global method of doing this. It entirely depends on how the data is being loaded, and what library/control is doing it.

Comment: Assuming you're loading with AJAX, set the cursor when you make the request, then change the cursor back in the success/onload callback.

Comment: Loading a new page, Im using Laravel's LengthAwarePaginator

Comment: This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/946676/2402610

Comment: @MahmoudMostafa Looks like thatll work, thank you

Comment: @Sam You are welcome my friend :)